# Error while accessing custom dll from PowerShell 1.0

Tags: c#, powershell

Following is my powershell script,

```
function hello()
{
    $dllpath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\raj\\pstest\\testlib.dll";
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath) | out-null;
    $obj = New-Object testlib.TestClass;
    $obj.print();
}

hello
```

Following is the TestClass in testlib which i am trying t access in powershell

```
using System;

namespace testlib
{
    class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
        }

        public void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

But i am getting error like below,

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [testlib.TestClass]: make sure the assembly conta
ining this type is loaded.
At C:\Documents and Settings\raj\pstest\script1.ps1:5 char:19
+     $obj = New-Object <<<<  testlib.TestClass;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewOb
   jectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Documents and Settings\raj\pstest\script1.ps1:6 char:12
+     $obj.print <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (print:String) [], RuntimeExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I have tried using add-type cmddlet but it is also giving the same response.
I guess the dll is getting loaded properly into the powershell but I am not able to instantiate the object of TestClass. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

If i remove out-null following is the output im getting,

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v2.0.50727     C:\Documents and Settings\553566\pstest\testlib.dll
New-Object : Cannot find type [testlib.TestClass]: make sure the assembly conta
ining this type is loaded.
At C:\Documents and Settings\raj\pstest\script1.ps1:5 char:19
+     $obj = New-Object <<<<  testlib.TestClass;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewOb
   jectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Documents and Settings\raj\pstest\script1.ps1:6 char:12
+     $obj.print <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (print:String) [], RuntimeExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: What is printed out when you remove out-null from `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllpath) | out-null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOPS my bad .........

The TestClass should be a public one :(

After that modification its working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[code]$dll = $($env:userprofile + '\pstest\testdll.dll')
And then try to invoke some static method from your library. For example:

Comment: Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or asse
mbly 'file:///C:\Documents and Settings\raj\pstest\testdll.dll' or one of it
s dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." error is comming

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dll = $($env:userprofile + '\pstest\test.dll')
 [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dll)
 [MyNamespace.MyClass]::Print()
```